# Check if iframe content has been loaded already

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I am trying to check if the iframe src has been already added the first time so that it does not load it again in the second time. The iframe is activated with the function given below, I am using jQuery to check this. Unfortunately the `console.log("loaded");` gets called every time the function is triggered. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <iframe id="iframe_01" style="
   position: fixed;
   margin: auto;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 10;
   display: none;
   ">
    </iframe>

<script>
function Activate_iFrame() {

    //iframe start
    let iframe_01 = document.getElementById("iframe_01");

    iframe_01.style.display = 'Block';

    if ($("#iframe_01").find("iframe").contents().find("body")) {
        console.log("loaded");
        iframe_01.src = "LINK TO WEBSITE";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `I am trying to check if the iframe src has been already added the first time so that it does not load it again in the second time.` this is completely opposite to what the code in the question does. The code in the question is determining if there is a `body` already within the content of the `iframe` and then changing the content to another URL entirely. Can you please edit the question to be cleaer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a flag to your code to stop the test running a second time

```
let iframeLoaded = false;

function Activate_iFrame() {

    //iframe start
    let iframe_01 = document.getElementById("iframe_01");

    iframe_01.style.display = 'Block';

    if (!iframeLoaded &&$("#iframe_01").find("iframe").contents().find("body")) {
        console.log("loaded");
        iframeLoaded = true;
        iframe_01.src = "LINK TO WEBSITE";
    }
}
```